# Occurrence of a word in a line

Tags: c++, string

I have written this code to find number of occurrences of a word in a line.

It worked fine on my Cygwin terminal.
But now when I run it on my Linux machine it is crashing at `strcpy(line, strstr(line,word))`

Why such behaviour?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int findWord(char* line,char* word)
{
    int count=0;

    int wordLen = strlen(word);

    while(true)
    {
     if( strstr(line,word) == NULL)
     break;

     strcpy(line, strstr(line,word)); //Crashes here
     printf("@@%s\n",line);
     strcpy(line,line+wordLen+1);
     printf("##%s\n",line);
     count++;
     }
printf("%d\n",count);
return count;
}

int main()
{
    cout <<   findWord("One Two Three Four One Two One Four","Three") << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: Edited the title . This is common to both C and C++**

Comment: `cout <<` not in `C`.

Comment: This is not C, this is C++.

Comment: @cha5on Please refer function findWord(char* line,char* word)
This is 'c' . I just tried to run it on visual studio c++

Comment: I'm aware those are C functions, but you're just calling C functions from C++.  Yes, it's pedantic.

Comment: @GauravK: Yes, the problem with your program seems to be one that is common to both C and C++, but in general, be careful with the differences between C and C++. Sometimes there are subtle (and not so subtle) differences between these two languages, and exactly the same code may or may not work the same. Especially when having a problem that you don't know the cause of, I would recommend to be a bit pedantic with which language you are using.

Comment: Since you are compiling it as C++ code, didn't you get `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]`? If not, I suggest you up your warning level, `-Wall -Wextra` is reasonable with *gcc*. Oh, and then do fix the warnings you get, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

Your pointer **line** points to (the first character in) the constant string "One Two Three Four One Two One Four". You try to overwrite this string, which is undefined behaviour since a C implementation should be allowed to put it in read-only memory. Anything can happen. In Cygwin it happened to work as you expected, and in Linux it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

`char* line`

it's pointer and pointed it at a constant string. The compiler puts that in a part of memory that is marked as read-only.Modifying it cause [Undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).